# Wrong wording of rate limiting message when editing tag wikis

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, rate-limiting

When editing tag wikis, you're limited to one edit per 30 seconds (see the [rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232)). However, the displayed message is slightly confusing:

> You can perform this action again in 30 seconds.

That's wrong; you don't have to wait 30 seconds, it just needs to be at least 30 seconds after the previous edit. It should either be

> You can perform this action again in *x* seconds.

(where *x* is the appropriate value)
or something like

> You can only make changes to tag wikis once every 30 seconds.

(both 'styles' appear in different rate-limiting messages, I don't have a preference).

[image]